# Blazor Running in IIS - "AN ERROR HAS OCCURED. THIS APPLICATION MAY NO LONGER RESPOND UNTIL RELOADED"

Tags: iis, blazor

I have Blazor App (.Net Core 3.1), the App Run fines in Visual Studio. I deployed (Visual Studio Web Deploy to localhost) Published the App to Windows Server 2019. I set the Application Pool to "No Managed Code". When I browse to the app  (servername/TestAPP)   I get "**AN ERROR HAS OCCURED. THIS APPLICATION MAY NO LONGER RESPOND UNTIL RELOADED"**.  I have installed the same App on a Windows 2016 Server - with the same configuration. It works fine on Window 2016 (?????). IIS_IUSRS has full permissions to the folder.  Any ideas?  Thx in advance.

Comment: Nothing in browser console.   Running Unmanaged App pool.  How do I 'see' the actual error?

Comment: you could try to set detailed error in iis 1)Open Internet Information Services (IIS) 2)ManagerSelect "Error Pages" 3)Select "Edit Feature Settings" 4)Select "Detailed Errors" and try to refresh the site page. Share the snapshot of the detailed error. if you are hosting as an application you could try to set the base href URL in the site.